# context of defmulti with respects to binding

Tags: clojure

Are functions dispatched by `defmulti` executing in the context/scope of the dispatcher?

I want to set a dynamic var `*foo*` for dispatched `defmethod` call.

I have a feeling that I will need to wrap the call to the dispatcher but wanted to confirm with the Clojure magicians.

**RESOLVED**

As per underlying suspicions confirmed by @schaueho, the following does what I need

```
;; Multimethod dispatch

(defmulti consume :type)

;; wrapper for dispatch

(defn consume-it [{:keys [token-fn]:as expression}]
  "Wraps consume to imbue term name resolutions"
  (if token-fn
    (binding [*lookup-fn* token-fn]
      (consume expression))
    (consume expression)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to use `binding` within the dispatch function. The purpose of the dispatch function is to return a value that will be used to identify the method to invoke, not to actually call the identified method.

```
(def ^:dynamic *dynvar* nil)

(defmulti mymulti
  (fn [two args]
    (binding [*dynvar* (new-value two args)]
       (compute-dispatch-value two args)))
```

In this example, `compute-dispatch-value` would be see the new binding of `*dynvar*`, but any invoked method afterwards wouldn't.

Comment: Yes, as I noted in my question there was a sneaky feeling that I would need to wrap the dispatch call within a `binding` (which I have done and works for what I need).